# SQL: combine multiple AND with OR in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, combinations, where-clause

I have a simple problem, but at the moment I'm waiting for the big idea...
I want to create a WHERE clause with nested AND and OR and bring an example in pseudocode.

Planing my holiday depends on three things:
a) weather is fine
AND
b) food is fine
AND
c) people are fine

"people are fine" means:
c1) John is here AND Sue is here
OR
c2) Bill is here AND Marilyn is here

I tried:

```
WHERE weather = fine
AND food = good
AND (
  (John is here AND Sue is here)
  OR (Bill is here AND Marilyn is here)
)
```

But it does not works (maybe my brain is thinking in the wrong programming language ..)

Thanks for help! (to start my holidays ... ;-) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I can only add an answer but not comment so far.
The pseudocode looks totally fine.
I guess the problem is the actual SQL syntax.
Please share the exact SQL code.

And what does your SQL system answer when you try your code?

Does it send an error message or is just the result not what you expect?

Comment: I should better go biking or hiking ....
Sorry, my very bad. It was not the WHERE clause - I messed up something with the identifiers. Thanks for your quick reply.